# Will compression be supported with Dataframes API read_csv?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, apache-beam-io

Not sure if I can ask this here.
But I really like the idea of the [Dataframe API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) for beam.
But unfortunately "compression" is currently not supported for `read_csv`.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ac12f52a28ffa738772ffd0128e16adebbdd7ad2/sdks/python/apache_beam/dataframe/io.py#L233

Can someone tell me if this is on the roadmap and by when it can be expected.

I would really like to do it myself, but I am pretty new to beam.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.